# Resize the font size of selected text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to resize the `font-size` of text in a `div` .I know the JavaScript code, but here what I want is only resizing the `font-size` of div having the focus or currently user selected `div`.

```js
$("#slider").on("change",function(){
    var v=$(this).val();
    $('.text').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="12" max="120" id="slider" />
<div class="text"  contenteditable="true"  style="cursor:grab;">hello</div>
<div class="text text1"  contenteditable="true" style="cursor:grab;">hello</div>
<div class="text text2"  contenteditable="true"  style="cursor:grab;">hello</div>
<div class="text text3"  contenteditable="true"  style="cursor:grab;">hello</div>
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code into your script tag

```
$('.text').on('focus',function(){
    $('.text').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

And change slider onChange function to this

```
$("#slider").on("change",function(){
   var v=$(this).val();
   $('.text.active').css('font-size', v + 'px');
});
```

Here you can see how it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwy4oge8/

Comment: could you please check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191439/click-event-is-not-working-in-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with jquery. here is a working javascript code.

```
         var focused = null;[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".text"),
    function (x) {
        x.onfocus = function () { focused = this;};
    });
    document.querySelector("#slider").onchange = function () {
        focused != null ? focused.style.fontSize = this.value + "px" : true;;
```